# Create Angular 2 project inside Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, angular, angular-cli

I'm new in Angular 2 and I want to create a new project in Angular 2. My IDE is Eclipse Luna and I want to create this Angular project inside one of the folders of a project created in Eclipse. For example, the image below shows my existing project:

[image: This is my project]

What I want it's create the Angular 2 project in a folder inside "admin". I've tried using the CLI created by the Angular team using

```
ng new angular-project
```

It creates all files and folders, but when I'm going to the "index.html" or it shows "Loading..." and using

```
ng serve
```

It doesn't work neither. So there is any chance to create an Angular project inside an Eclipse project or should I create a "New Angular 2 project"?

Comment: sorry I'm not  a java developer..but when you see loading is your webserver active? .. any error in chrome console?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `angular-cli` is a good start. The cli starts its own webserver using the webpack-dev-server. You should navigate to:

```
localhost:4200
```

This is the default port of the cli. You can also use the `-o` variable to start the browser and it will navigate to the right url. You should not run the `index.html` directly from eclipse. The base url set inside the index.html probably does not correspond well, and the build files are not in that location. They are actually in memory

Comment: It doesn't work. After create the project and run the comand `ng serve`, I'm going to the `localhost:4200` but tells me that "It could not connect. Firefox can't stablish a connxion..."

Comment: what does: "it doesn't work mean", what do you see? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: It doesn't work. After create the project and run the comand `ng serve`, I'm going to the `localhost:4200` but tells me that "It could not connect. Firefox can't stablish a connexion..."

Comment: Moreover, afert run the comand `ng serve` it looks like it works, but the last line in putty shows "webpack: budle is now VALID" and I can't write anything else in it

Comment: Yes, you should leave it running. That's your webserver. Don't close it. Is your development not on localhost?

Comment: Ok, it's running but the browser still showing "Unable to connect. Firefox can't stablish a connection to the server at localhost:4200". Firebug shows "localhost:4200, state: aborted"